# How do I open a PDF file List in a new Window in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

How do I open a PDF file List in dialog box in a new Window in an ASP.NET application ?

I want list of pdf file which is stored in folder in my application and then select any of pdf and save in logged user's particular folder.

Comment: You need to provide more information and be specific about what you are struggling with.  For instance, are you trying to diplay a list of PDF files available in your application or do you want to add a PDF file to your application using a file input.

Comment: first i want to select pdf from list and download pdf then also edit pdf and finaly edited pdf saved in logged user's folder.

Comment: Your question is too broad in that you are asking for a complete solution as opposed to some point you are sticking on.  Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: ok give me one solution about how to open folder in new window that i can see list of stored pdf file in folder on button's click event.

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to display a list of pdf files stored in a folder on the server side you will need to render the list to a page in some format that makes sense.  You *may* open that up as a dialog (perhaps using something like jquery ui) but it wouldn't be necessary.

Next to each file you could have a button that indicates the action you are after, say 'Copy'.

This would then send the id/name of the relevant file to the server and the server code could copy the file to some other location on the server that you refer to as the users folder.

However, if you want to download the file to the user's machine that is something else and you will find many answer here on SO about that.